# Show the points $u,v,w$ are not collinear

Tags: differential-topology

Consider triples of points $u,v,w \in R^2$, which we may consider as single points $(u,v,w) \in R^6$. Show that for almost every $(u,v,w) \in R^6$, the points $u,v,w$ are not collinear.

I think I should use Sard's Theorem, simply because that is the only "almost every" statement in differential topology I've read so far. But I have no idea how to relate this to regular value etc, and to solve this problem.

Another Theorem related to this problem is Fubini Theorem (for measure zero):

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $R^n$ such that $A \cap V_c$ has measure zero in $V_c$ for all $c \in R^k$. Then $A$ has measure zero in $R^n$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $u,v,w$ are collinear iff $\det \begin{bmatrix} u-w & v-w \end{bmatrix} = 0$. And the result in http://www.uwindsor.ca/math/sites/uwindsor.ca.math/files/05-03.pdf

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks a lot for the reference, @copper.hat

Comment: You are very welcome! What is $V_c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u,v,$ and $w$ are collinear if and only if there is some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ with $w=v+\lambda(v-u)$.  We can thus define a smooth function

$$\begin{array}{rcl}f:\mathbb{R}^5&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^6\\(u,v,\lambda)&\longmapsto&(u,v,v+\lambda(v-u))\end{array}$$

By the equivalence mentioned in the first sentence, the image of $f$ is exactly the points $(u,v,w)$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ with $u,v,$ and $w$ collinear.  Now, because $5<6$, every point in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is a critical point, so that the entire image of $f$ has measure $0$, by Sard's theorem.

Comment: Hi Jared, thank you for your help, but I still have no clue about what is the image of $f$ and how to proceed from there.

Comment: @MathSnail: Note the addition in my answer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jared, thank you so much!